# How to give different Load for Transaction Controller in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have created the test case in Jmeter

```
Test Plan 
  - Transaction Controller (Login)
     - Login
     - Home Page
  - Transaction Controller (Payment)
     - Make Payment
     - Search Payment
     - Schedule Payment
  - Transaction Controller (Online Services)
     - Cheque Request
     - Card Replacement
  - Transaction Controller (Add Beneficiary)
      - Add Beneficiary
      - Activate Beneficiary
  - Transaction Controller (Account Services)
       - Mini Statement
       - Balance
```

................. it goes on

We have tried 3000 users for all the scenarios. But business team has the requirement like all the users don't want to hit all the request as it can not be realistic. They have priority like

```
Login ~ 50%
Payment ~ 20%
Account Service ~  20%
General Service ~ 2%
etc.,
```

Jmeter's default behavior is to run all the request indenpendently and will run all the request for the thread count which is configured.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: is it possible to go to payment without login?

Comment: Login is mandatory for all flows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add several Thread Groups with different numbers of users.
Such as 50 users for Thread Group with logins
20 users for Thread group with Payments, etc.

Comment: would it be suggestable if we use switch as well?

Comment: @ChanGan sure, you may use switch also

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve there are multiple options:

1. You can use different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent the different groups of virtual users
2. You can use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) which controls how often its children are executed
3. You can use [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to provide flexible critera
4. You can go for [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide) which combines the power of the Switch Controller with the ease of use of the Throughput Controller. This guy doesn't come with JMeter, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) . Convert Transaction Controller to  Throughput Controller in " Percent executions " mode. Set Throughput in Throughput controller according to your need , Like : Login - 50 , Payment -20 etc

Comment: Hi, Login is mandatory for all the modules to run.. Login should be 100 and the rest of module should be what % we need actually right?

Comment: Yes 100 % would work. Also If login is mandatory then keeping it as transaction controller ( Not converting it to Throughput controller) would also work.